# What is the practical relevance of the wordsize when using a Hash?

Tags: hash, blocksize

I understand that the word size is the internal "working package size" below the block size of a cryptographic hash function (and a block cipher), as each block is broken into words an than processed round-based. Does this size have any practical relevance when using that function? For instance do algorithms with 64b word size perform better on 64b machines? Or does aligning the message-to-hash at the word size have any impact?

Comment: It is mainly a performance thing, although some algorithms can be bit-sliced to perform well on smaller word size processors, such as Keccak. SHA-512 can not be bit-sliced as far as I am aware, and has poor performance with 32-bit calculations. Be aware in these cases that a 32-bit processor can still perform 64-bit calculations if it has the appropriate instructions and registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the internal word size of a hash algorithm has some significance, pretty much for the reasons given in the question.

Algorithms with 64-bit word size have a (typically sizable) performance edge on 64-bit machines (more precisely: for large messages, and comparable implementations, the ratio of the number of bytes hashed in a given time over that for a comparable algorithm with 32-bit word size will likely be significantly higher using a 64-bit machine and making good use of the architecture, than this ratio is on a 32-bit machine). For this reason we have SHA-512/256, a 256-bit hash obtained by truncating to 256-bit a natively 512-bit hash with internal 64-bit word size: on a 64-bit machine, SHA-512/256 can be faster than SHA-256, a natively 256-bit hash with internal 32-bit word size. See [this](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/548) for more details.

And, on most machines, there is some (typically small) performance penalty if the message to hash is not aligned to the native word size.

Comment: For more real world performance numbers of SHA256 vs SHA512 see my chart at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2 which compares performance on modern processors with optimized algorithms